# Change base url in django-tastypie-swagger

Tags: python, django, tastypie, swagger

I have a Django site running with Gunicorn on port 62022 and a Nginx running on port 62090. The port that is open to the outside world is 62090 (where Nginx listen). The problem is that `django-tastypie-swagger` thinks the base url is http://localhost:62022/ and it can not make the documentation for the API because that url does not respond.

Is there a way to set the base url to whatever I need instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try insert this into settings.py

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "base_path": 'localhost:62090/',
}
```

of course instead localhost insert your domain